# Exercise 8.13 - Brezis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}$). Set
$$
D_{h}u(x) = \frac{1}{h}(u(x+h) - u(x)), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}, h> 0
$$
Show that $D_{h}u \to u'$ in  $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}$) as $h \to 0$.

**I'm trying to use the fact that $C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}$) is dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}$)**

Comment: The Mean Value Theorem and Dominated Convergence Theorem should do it, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: cross posted in math stackexchange. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441553/exercise-8-13-brezis

Comment: @DavidHughes Did not help!!!

Comment: @kodlu Did not help

Comment: @David Hughes  I think it is not that easy. If you know  a very short proof I would like to see it.

Comment: @Yuval Peres yes you are correct. I misread the question and thought it was only for smooth $u$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The proof is not short, because it is done from first principles, without using any theorems about Sobolev space except its definition.

By the definition of $W^{1,p}$, there exist $v_n \in  C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$
and $w \in  L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that $v_n \to u$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $v_n' \to w$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. In this case we write $u'=w$.
Note that $v_n'$ is a classical derivative, so
$$D_h v_n(x)=\frac{v_n(x+h)-v_n}{h}= I_h(v_n')(x) \,, \tag{1}
$$
where for $f\in  L^p(\mathbb{R})$, we write
$$I_h(f)(x):=\int_0^h \frac{f(x+t)}{h} \,dx  \,.$$
By Jensen's inequality [1], for all $n \ge 1 $ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$|I_h(v_n')(x)-I_h(u')(x)|^p \le \frac{1}{h} \int_0^h |v_n'(x+t)-u'(x+t)|^p \,dt \,.
$$
Integrating both sides $\,dx$ and using Fubini on the right-hand side, we obtain
$$\|I_h(v_n') -I_h(u') \|^p \le \frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \|v_n'(\cdot+t)-u'(\cdot+t)\|_p^p \,dt=  \|v_n' -u' \|_p^p \,.\tag{2}
$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, find $k$ such that
$$ \|v_k'-u'\|_p<\epsilon \,. \tag{3}
$$
Let $M$ denote the Lebesgue measure of the support of $v_k$.
Since $v_k'$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $h_0\in(0,1)$ such that
$$\forall t\in [0, h_0], \quad \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |v_k'(x+t)-v_k'(x)|<\epsilon/(M+1)  \,,$$
so for $h\in [0, h_0]$ and all $x$, we have
$|I_h (v_k')(x)-v_k'(x)|<\epsilon/(M+1)$, whence
$$\|I_h (v_k') -v_k'\|_p^p \le (M+h) (\epsilon/(M+1))^p <\epsilon^p \,.$$
In conjunction with $(2)$ and $(3)$, this gives
$$\|I_h(u')-u' \|_p \le \|I_h(u')-I_h(v_k') \|_p + \|I_h(v_k')-v_k' \|_p + \| v_k' -u'\|_p <3\epsilon \,. \tag{4}$$

Next, fix $h\in [0, h_0]$, and choose $m=m(h,\epsilon)$ such that
$$\|u-v_m  \|_p<\epsilon h \quad \text{and} \quad \|u'-v_m'\|_p<\epsilon \,.
$$
The first inequality implies that $\|D_h(u) -D_h(v_m) \|_p<2\epsilon$. Therefore, by $(1),\, (2)$ and $(4)$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\|D_h(u)-u'\|_p &\le& 
\|D_h(u) -D_h(v_m) \|_p+\|I_h(v_m')-I_h(u')\|_p+\|I_h(u')-u' \|_p \\
&<& 2\epsilon+\epsilon+3\epsilon=6\epsilon \,.
\end{eqnarray}
This completes the proof.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @AGL. I hope you find it clear. This took me a couple of hours to write down carefully without using any prior theorems. I assume you know how to accept an answer?

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$Re-define, if needed, the function $u$ on a set of Lebesgue measure zero so that
\begin{equation}
    u(y)-u(x):=\int_x^y dt\, u'(t)
\end{equation}
for all real $x$ and $y$ such that $x\le y$.
Then we can write
\begin{equation}
    (D_hu)(x) =\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}h
    =\int_0^1 ds\,u'(x+sh),
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
\|D_hu-u'\|_p^p&=\int_\R dx\,\Big|\int_0^1 ds\,(u'(x+sh)-u'(x))\Big|^p \\ 
&\le\int_\R dx\,\int_0^1 ds\,|u'(x+sh)-u'(x)|^p \\ 
&=\int_0^1 ds\,\int_\R dx\,|u'(x+sh)-u'(x)|^p=:I_h(u'). 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Take any real $\ep>0$. Since $C_c(\R)$ is dense in $L^p(\R)$, there is a function $v\in C_c(\R)$ such that $\|u'-v\|_p\le\ep$. Using the Jensen inequality
\begin{equation}
    \Big(\frac{a+b+c}3\Big)^p\le\frac{a^p+b^p+c^p}3
\end{equation}
for nonnegative $a,b,c$, we get
\begin{equation}
    |u'(x+sh)-u'(x)|^p\le3^{p-1}(|v(x+sh)-v(x)|^p+|u'(x+sh)-v(x+sh)|^p+|u'(x)-v(x)|^p),
\end{equation}
whence
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
I_h(u')\le3^{p-1}(I_h(v)+2\ep^p). 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
It remains to show that $I_h(v)\to0$ as $h\to0$. But this follows because $v$ is in $C_c(\R)$, so that $v$ has a compact support and is uniformly continuous.

Comment: The first identity in your answer, $$(D_hu)(x) =\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}h
 =\int_0^1 ds\,u'(x+sh)$$ needs some justification, as $u$ is just a function in Sobolev space, and is formally just defined a.e.  In particular, $u'$ is not a classical derivative.

Comment: I want to thank everyone

Comment: @YuvalPeres : We can just re-define the function $u$ appropriately on a set of measure $0$ so as to make $u$ absolutely continuous -- and this is what I meant. I have now added the corresponding detail. I think this only simplifies the proof a bit.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis That is correct, but this identity does not follow from the definition of the weak derivative in Sobolev space- it needs an additional argument or reference. Even after adding that, your proof is still likely to be shorter than mine. One place where this is discussed is the book by Evans and Gariepy, Theorem 4.9.1

Comment: @YuvalPeres : I think this is a well-known fact. E.g., Wikipedia has this: "In the one-dimensional problem it is enough to assume that the ${\displaystyle (k{-}1)}$-th derivative ${\displaystyle f^{(k-1)}}$ is differentiable almost everywhere and is equal almost everywhere to the Lebesgue integral of its derivative" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#One-dimensional_case)

Comment: @YuvalPeres : BTW, the definition of $W^{1,p}$ that you used in your answer differs from what I learned about 50 years ago as a student, which is the same as the one given in Wikipedia, which I think is the common one. I think the denseness of $C^1_c$ in $W^{1,p}$ is then a theorem, which of course shows that your definition is equivalent to what I think is the common one.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for explaining, indeed, we started from different definitions.